# How to get ALL shopify orders via API (limited to 250)

Tags: php, r, shopify, httr, shopify-app

Hi I am trying to get all Orders from a shopify store via shopify API,  I am using an R script and so far I am only able to get 250 records that is the limit per page, if I dont use the limit keyword in the php it defaults it to 50.

Here is what I have so far

```
library(dplyr)
library(httr)
library(rlist)
library(jsonlite)

apikey <- "xxxxxxxxxx1d2fd1fb8710"
pass <- "xxxxxxxxxxxx3e4d38d476fdb188ac7"

orders <- GET(
  url = "https://xxxxx-xxxxx.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json?query=&limit=250&status=any", 
  authenticate(user = apikey, password = pass)
)
```

If I want to do the same via PHP I use the https call and I get the same 250 results

```
https://1x877xxxxbd3ed99ae30d1eb4d71cxxx:dcfee3235061bd149ebxxxxxxxxxxxxx@store.myshopify.com/admin/orders.json?query=&limit=250&status=any
```

Is there a way that I can get ALL orders in one call?

Or if not, is there a way to get different pages, like page 1,2,3,4,5 etc and later on I can union those dataframes into 1.

Comment: as the api docs say, the max is 250

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use paging. Clearly described in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

As others have said, you have to use pagination. I recently created an R package called [shopr](https://github.com/ben519/shopr) that makes this fairly easy.

```
library(shopr)

orders <- shopr_get_orders(
  shopURL = "https://xxxxx-xxxxx.myshopify.com",
  APIKey = apikey,
  APIPassword = pass,
  APIVersion = "2019-04",
  max_pages = Inf,         # this is the default
  limit_per_page = 250L,   # this is the default
  since_id = 0L            # this is the default
)
```

shopr will make successive calls to the API, fetching chunks of 250 orders and then combine them together for you.